# Javascript variables using loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have some input elements like

```
<input type="text" name="d1">
<input type="text" name="d2">
```

and so on

```
<input type="text" name="d10">
```

Now I would like to select all of them for some javascript query
document.form_name.d1
through
document.form_name.d10, using a for loop, so that I dont have to write each one of them separately.
How to do this?

Comment: please show html

Comment: Add them a class and select by class.

Comment: Thanks u_mulder and Nikita. Will try both and get back to you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Add some class to your inputs and use `getElementsByClassName`:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('text-input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(inputs[i].value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="d1" class="text-input" value="value 1">
<input type="text" name="d2" class="text-input" value="value 2">
<input type="text" name="d3" class="text-input" value="value 3">
<input type="text" name="d4" class="text-input" value="value 4">
<input type="text" name="d5" class="text-input" value="value 5">
```

Comment: I think this solution is better than Nikita's because it is more scalable. This avoids "name" having 2 responsibilities (naming the field, and knowing if this field should be taken from its list). Imagine that the names of the fields change, or that its selection should not contain d2, but d1 and d3, etc ...)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use javasctipt querySelectorAll to get all elements starts with "d"

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name^=d]");
```

Comment: Thanks u_mulder and Nikita. Will try both and get back to you guys.